# How to make the size of columns responsive to the number of elements?

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to make responsive grid layout where the last row might has less elements in case of odd number of elements, but anyway it needs to be stretched on full width. Elements will be added in admin so we have just quantity of elements and space for some condition in css/js. How can i do it?

I tried auto-fit, but i don't know how to split it on equal rows

Here is an example of how I want it:
[image: Example of how I want]

Comment: Not possible dynamically with CSS

Comment: Flexbox might help but you would need to define the number of columns

Comment: You can do a similar thing with flexbox using flex-grow, flex basis, and flex-wrap. However, the bahaviour of "7 elements" is not possible. The minimum width will be set and won't change based on the number of elemnts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex` instead of `grid`:

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   gap: 5px;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.container > * {
  flex: 1 15%;
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```